Why does extractability not contradict zero-knowledge?
I was introduced to the QR-protocol that shows that a number y is a quadratic residue modulo x through an interactive protocol. The protocol is perfect zero-knowledge but it also proves that the prover P knows the square root w (a witness) of y modulo x, meaning it is a zero-knowledge proof of knowledge. By interacting with the prover multiple times an extractor algorithm that runs in expected polynomial time is able to extract w from its interaction with P. Why does this not contradict that the protocol is perfect zero-knowledge?

The knowledge extraction algorithm has more power than a verifier who participates in the ZK interaction -- it can rewind time.
Consider a typical ZK protocol with 3 messages, where the prover sends the first one:

Prover: send $M_1$ to verifier
Verifier: send $M_2$ to prover
Prover: send $M_3$ to verifier.

A typical knowledge extraction algorithm works by doing the following:

Run the prover until it produces $M_1$
Choose $M_2$ and give it to the prover
Run the prover until it produces $M_3$
Return the prover to the internal state it had after step 1
Choose a different $M'_2$ and give it to the prover
Run the prover until it produces $M'_3$
From the combination of these values, compute the witness

You can think of the knowledge extraction algorithm as running the prover inside a virtual machine, and restoring the VM image to an earlier state -- from the perspective of the prover, rewinding time and attempting a different timeline.
A verifier cannot cause the same thing to happen in a typical interaction with the prover.
Even if the verifier interacts with the prover multiple times, there is a subtle difference:

Interact with the prover and receive $M_1$ from it
Choose $M_2$ and give it to the prover
Receive $M_3$ from the prover
Ask the prover to prove the same thing again. This time, the prover sends $M'_1$
Choose $M'_2$ and give it to the prover
Receive $M'_3$ from the prover

The verifier sees two transcripts $(M_1, M_2, M_3)$ and $(M'_1, M'_2, M'_3)$, where $M_1$ and $M'_1$ are chosen independently (by the prover).
But the knowledge extraction algorithm sees two transcripts $(M_1, M_2, M_3)$ and $(M_1, M_2', M_3')$ with the same $M_1$!
The verifier cannot say "please prove the same thing again, and don't forget to use the same $M_1$ as last time" because the protocol instructs the prover to generate $M_1$ fresh for each interaction.
This is precisely the advantage that typical knowledge extraction algorithms use to extract the witness, and why the regular verifier cannot do the same thing.
I recommend that you read about Schnorr's identification protocol, which is the simplest protocol whose extraction works in this way.

Thanks for the great explanation and the recommendation!
